# How to setup SSH tunnel to connect to my ElasticSearch and MongoDB residing on AWS EC2 server?

Tags: windows, mongodb, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying SSH tunneling for the first time hence, I'm expecting some level of guidance (with explanation) to setup an SSH tunnel so that I from my Windows client machine can connect to things like ElasticSearch and MongoDB that are residing on AWS EC2 Windows Server.

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you can make tunnel to server for MongoDB,

```
ssh -L 9999:127.0.0.1:27017 user@serverip -NnT
```

Now you are able to access your remote mongodb through tunnel on port 9999 so you can now connect to mongodb server from local like,

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9992
```

The same way you can also create your own tunnel for elasticsearch also by specifying Port of elastic search like below,

```
ssh -L 9200:127.0.0.1:9200 user@serverip -NnT
```

Not have more knowledge of accessing elastic through port but this might help.

Comment: Does this command work for Windows as well? Also, if you could give me further explanation of the commands

Comment: Not sure about windows in putty but this command works fine for macOs and Ubunutu

Comment: Should I run the commands on my client Windows machine or on the AWS EC2 Windows machine?

Comment: What is `user@serverip` in the command? Am I supposed to replace it with something else?

Comment: Yes you need to replace this by like root@your_aws_cloud_Server_ip

Comment: how you connect to your AWS cloud server using password or using pem file it will depend on it

Comment: Here `9999:127.0.0.1:27017` 9999 is the newly assigned port number which can be used to connect, but is `127.0.0.1:27017` private IP of the AWS server?

Comment: No that 127.0.0.1 is your your machine default ip